# Immediately after class definition is complete, where are all of the references to the class object located?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Four references to a class are produced when a class is created which that never had a `__classcell__` passed in the namespace argument of `type.__new__`, aka a class with no functions that ever need the opcode `LOAD_NAME - __class__`. I can account for one, but since I can barely read C I can only speculate about the other 3. Most obviously, the first is the reference in the `__dict__` of the module the class was defined in. Another I think one is in a cache in `typeobject.c`. After a while if the reference count of a class drops below 4 it is destroyed, which is a good thing for classes defined in in function since there's no way to delete it after the function has been executed. 
Also there is perhaps a reference in whatever `type.mro` uses to generate mros.

Finally, I'm guessing the last is somewhere zero argument `super` can access, and that is the real info I'm after: why does a function created outside a class definition not work with zero argument `super`, even when it has `'__class__'` in its `__code__.co_names` and a cell with the class in its `__closure__`? A `RuntimeError: super(): __class__ cell not found` is still produced.

Classes that had a `__classcell__` (I say *had* because I believe that name is eventually deleted) have 5 references upon creation, one more than not. Seeing as the cell containing the class object in the `__closure__` of all functions that mention zero argument `super()` or `__class__` are identical I think it's a good bet that the additional reference is used by the `types.FunctionType.__closure__` descriptor to produce the `tuple` containing the cells.

Comment: It sounds like you asked this question as part of an attempt to debug some `super`-related issue. If you can produce an MCVE where the externally-defined function actually has a `__class__` closure variable pointing to the class and `super` can't find it, you may want to ask a question specifically about that.

Answer (score 3):

Let's take a look with [`gc.get_referrers`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gc.html#gc.get_referrers):

```
>>> import gc
>>> import pprint
>>> class Foo: pass
... 
>>> pprint.pprint(gc.get_referrers(Foo))
[<attribute '__dict__' of 'Foo' objects>,
 <attribute '__weakref__' of 'Foo' objects>,
 (<class '__main__.Foo'>, <class 'object'>),
 {'Foo': <class '__main__.Foo'>,
  '__annotations__': {},
  '__builtins__': <module 'builtins' (built-in)>,
  '__cached__': None,
  '__doc__': None,
  '__loader__': <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x7ff284402da0>,
  '__name__': '__main__',
  '__package__': None,
  '__spec__': None,
  'gc': <module 'gc' (built-in)>,
  'pprint': <module 'pprint' from '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/pprint.py'>}]
```

We can see in this list that the 3 references you were missing are from the `__dict__` and `__weakref__` [descriptors](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#implementing-descriptors) and the class's [`__mro__`](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/). (It might not be obvious that the third entry is the `__mro__`, but we can confirm:)

```
>>> gc.get_referrers(Foo)[2] is Foo.__mro__
True
```

The `__dict__` and `__weakref__` descriptors manage access to the `__dict__` and `__weakref__` attributes of `Foo` instances, and they need a reference to `Foo` for type checking, to make sure they're only used on `Foo` instances.

The `__mro__` is the sequence of classes Python searches to resolve class attributes of `Foo`, and to resolve instance attributes of `Foo` which are managed by a data descriptor or which don't have an entry in the instance `__dict__`.